# Represent list of lists as formatted grid

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I have tried to figure out how to make these changes, but it mostly just ends up with me making it ten times worse.

```
Insert[
 Multicolumn[
  Flatten[
   Table[
    {p, TraditionalForm@FullSimplify[ ((p - 2) n^2 - (p - 4) n)/2]},
    {p, 3, 32, 1}
    ]
   ],
  {12, 5}
  ],
 Alignment -> Center,
2
]
```

Needs to become

[image: this is what the code needs to become]

Answer (score 6):

```
{p, ((p - 2) n^2 - (p - 4) n)/2 // Distribute} /. p -> Range[3, 32] // Transpose;
TraditionalForm@TableForm[Partition[%, 5], TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

### Explanation

Since most arithmetic operations are performed element-wise over lists (e.g. `{a, b} + 1 -> {a + 1, b + 1}`), we can strip the `Table` and just replace `p` with the list of given values.  Then we can use [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) to bring in the `1/2` term.  And finally, since the list now has the structure

```
{
  {3,           4,   5,            ...},
  {n^2/2 + n/2, n^2, 3n^2/2 + n/2, ...}
}
```

and we want to pair up the elements in each column, we can use a good ol' fashion [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Then for the formatting into a grid, we need to [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) the list of lists into a 5x7x2 array, and then use [`TableForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) with the [`TableAlignments`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableAlignments.html) option, and finally, to make it all pretty, we wrap the whole thing in a [`TraditionalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to MSE. Here is one way

```
table = Table[{p, TraditionalForm@Expand[((p - 2) n^2 - (p - 4) n)/2]}, {p, 3, 32}];
table // Map[Column[#, Center] &] // Partition[#, 5] & // Grid
```

[image]